# Gradle - Single build.gradle with dynamic dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So we have a huge multi-project codebase with structure like below:

```
C:\Eclipse\Workspace->
                    AR
                    DC
                    CI
                    ..
                    ..
```

Each project has a build.gradle file which has 80% of the code same with only dependencies section changing for all the projects.

> What I want to achieve:

I want to create a parent project named "BuildAllProjects" which would be the *ONLY* project having build.gradle, settings.gradle and gradle.properties and propose to have a properties file for mentioning the dependencies of each project, something like:

```
AR=j2ee,commons-lang,FW,DA,Common
DC=commons-codec,FW,DA,Common,spring-core
```

and then use the gradle expand[] properties to dynamically fill the dependencies for the project which I am building, so for instance, if I am building AR, I may want to run:

```
gradle -PAR build
```

which will read dependencies for "AR" from the properties and expand in the form :

```
dependencies {
   compile name 'j2ee'
   compile name 'commons-lang'
}
```

Do you guys think this is possible or is this the WORST way of achieving it? I am new to GRADLE overall and information provided above is based on knowledge that I have acquired in a weeks time. Please provide your suggestions to implement this at the BEST of gradle.

Thanks,
Yogendra

Answer (score 0):

Layering a properties file based build language on top of Gradle's build language doesn't strike me as desirable. Instead, I recommend to focus on writing clean and DRY Gradle build scripts. You can learn more about Gradle's powerful abstraction capabilities (configuration injection, script plugins, `buildSrc`, custom plugins and extensions, etc.) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

In a typical multi-project build, subproject build scripts mostly contain dependency declarations, whereas most other configuration happens in the root build script and/or script plugins.

Comment: so what you mean is each sub project will still have a build.gradle but will only have the dependencies while rest of the 80% code will go in the root build.gradle? I am still not able to understand as in how do the 2 gradle build files use each other?

Comment: It's all explained in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).